# Unable set active class to Main dropdown Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

index.cshtml

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="margin-left:-27px">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">PAGE1</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("TEST1", "Index", "TEST1")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("TEST2", "Index", "TEST2")</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("PAGE2", "Index", "PAGE2")</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('ul.nav.navbar-nav').find('a[href="' + location.pathname + '"]')
            .closest('li').addClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

Script is working perfect for simple `li` but not for `<a class="dropdown-toggle"` any help to `correct script` ?

actually when i clicked on `main menu PAGE1` it is `not executing script` , when I clicked in `sub menu TEST1` it is `executing script`and `location.pathname` is `/TEST1` but how do I make `main menu as active` ?

Comment: where is 'ul.nav.navbar-nav' element?

Comment: updated all html code in questions kindly check

Comment: There are no obvious errors per say. May be there is no match b/w the `heref` and `location.pathname`.

Comment: put the value of 'location.pathname' and rendered anchor tags here

Comment: actually when i clicked on `PAGE1` menu it is not executing script :( that is the issue , when I clicked in sub menu `TEST1` it is calling script and `location.pathname` is `/TEST1` 
but how do I make main menu as active ?

Comment: Your script is only being executed once when the page loads. It checks the URL against the href and sets the active class. If you want it to check every time a link is clicked, you have to put it in a click event.

Comment: so how can I make active that link?